# Vega Charts: need to get scale invert value for string data

Tags: vega

I have a scatter plot where the x and y axis fields are chosen by the user, the data is processed and binned in our code, and the bins, domains, etc. are fed to vega for visualization. But my selection brush only works with numeric data and the domains can be numeric, string, or datetime.

Is there any way to make it work for string data?
My code is triggered via callback on a signal listener that listens to a signal that looks like this:
(sorry, I can't provide more of the spec!)

```
{
  'name': 'sigName',
  'value': [], // 3 x 2 array of arrays [end coords, start data coords, end data coords]
  'on': [
    {
      'events':
      {
        'signal': 'endSig' // provides coords ( xy() ) for the mouseup event after dragging to create brush
      },
      'update': '[ slice(endSig), [invert("xScale", startSig[0]), invert("yScale", startSig[1])], [invert("xScale", endSig[0]), invert("yScale", endSig[1])] ]'
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an answer so I decided to simply return the start and end coordinates then apply those to my domain. The view's height and width are known so I can do something like this for my string domains in my callback:

```
xValue = (domain.length / this.view.width()) * xCoodinate
output = isStartCoordinate ? domain[Math.ceil(xValue)] : domain[Math.floor(xValue)]
```